# Django cms project for OpenShift. Where to place static files?

Tags: django, openshift, django-cms

I am working on a django-cms based web site but having trouble with the static files. As I am going to deploy the site to OpenShift, I have used the django-example to construct the site (https://github.com/openshift/django-example). This way I ended up with the following overall structure of my django project:

- root_folder

  - wsgi

    - media
    - static
    - my_project

      - my_app
      - templates

So as you see, it's a bit different from the standard Django dir structure. Django docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/) has told me the following:

1. Include django.contrib.staticfiles in INSTALLED_APPS: Done
2. Define a static url, e.g. STATIC_URL = '/static/‘: Done
3. Use static template tag to refer to static files, e.g. {% static "my_app/myexample.jpg" %}: Done

Furthermore, the static root is defined as

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(WSGI_DIR, 'static')

where WSGI_DIR points to the folder named wsgi.

I keep getting 404s in my dev environment where I use Debug=True, when I try to refer to the static files from my base template. I have tried to place them in the following locations with no luck:

/wsgi/static/

/wsgi/static/my_app/

/wsgi/my_project/static/

/wsgi/my_project/static/my_app/

/wsgi/my_project/my_app/static/

/wsgi/my_project/my_app/static/my_app/

Where should I place the static files, and have I configured it correctly?

Comment: Did you run `./manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: Do I need to do this in dev where I use `Debug=True`? The static files I am talking about, are some custom files that are manually placed in the static folder so there is nothing to collect.. Anyway, I tried running collectstatic and it makes no difference (it simply collects static files from all my installed apps, which isn't necessary as they already work fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that my_app was not in the INSTALLED_APPS list (apparently this is not part of the code structure I got from django-example). When I added the app to the list, it worked. The correct location of the static files: `/wsgi/my_project/my_app/static/my_app/`